# App (Win/Android) for managing and cataloging Lego sets

Tags: shopping, software, set-database

I'm looking for an app to keep track of my Lego sets. For my DVDs/BRs I'm using [DVD Profiler](http://www.invelos.com/):

- Desktop application (Win 7+)
- Android/iOS app
- They sync by using a single account
- But you can use all the apps offline as well

I don't need "fancy" functions like seeing what other sets I would be able to build with the bricks I own, I just want to add new sets on my PC (Win 7), then see which sets I own on my PC and an Android phone (offline as well!).

If I can set the purchase price and date (and maybe when I first/last built the set), that would be a huge plus but I can live without functions like that.

Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 3):

Brickset allows you to do all of the things you mentioned. It's very simple to use, but it also has some optional advanced features. You can read more about keeping track of your collection on Brickset here: https://brickset.com/mycollection

There are some [Brickset based apps](https://brickset.com/tools/mobileapps) providing options for Android and Windows 8+, although I'm not familiar enough with them to be able to recommend one that would work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately Brickset is a website and because of that I won't be able to manage my collection offline, which is a must for me. I'm looking for a Windows application with an Android "companion" app, maybe something that uses your Brickset profile?

Comment: There are some Brickset apps, although I'm not familiar enough with them to be able to recommend one that would work for you, but someone else might be able to point you in the right direction.